# Messing around with JPA and getting an Error creating user - could not set field value

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am following the Spring tutorial to get started with JPA, and I have a basic mysql db with a `user` table.

[image]

I've set up `User.java` as follows:

```
package com.test.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name="id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    String first_name;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    String last_name;

    @Column(name="username")
    String username;

    public User(String first_name, String last_name, String username) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public User() { } 

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

I've set up the `UserRepo.java`:

```
package com.test.models;


import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import java.util.UUID;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, UUID>{
    User findByUsername(String username);
```

}

And finally the `UserController.java`:

```
package com.test.controllers;

import com.test.models.UserRepo;
import com.test.models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/create")
    @ResponseBody
    public String create(String first_name, String last_name, String username) {
        String userId = "";
        try {
            User user = new User(first_name, last_name, username);
            userRepo.save(user);
            userId = String.valueOf(user.getId());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return "Error creating the user: " + ex.toString();
        }
        return "User successfully created with id = " + userId;
    }

}
```

I've also set up my db connection:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=fakepass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

However, when I use postman to make a POST to localhost:8080/create with

```
{
    "first_name": "Jim",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "username": "jim.smith"
}
```

I get this error:

> Error creating the user:
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field
>   value [ff80818158b79f8e0158b7a285b60001] value by reflection : [class
>   com.test.models.User.id] setter of com.test.models.User.id; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set
>   field value [ff80818158b79f8e0158b7a285b60001] value by reflection :
>   [class com.test.models.User.id] setter of com.test.models.User.id

Comment: can you change your fieldName to camelCase? Like `firstName` instead of `first_name`? And, also change the setter getter method accordingly? You don't need to change the column definition btw.
Your setter methods seem not being recognized.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Your strategy in @GenericGenerator is set incorrectly.

Try:

```
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
```

Answer (score 0):

All JPA entity classes should have the empty constructors and **your `User` class is missing empty constructor** which is causing this issue, so change your `User` Entity class as shown below and add `User()` constructor:

```
public class User {

    public User() {//empty constructor
    }

    //add existing code here

}
```

> The entity class must have a no-arg constructor. The entity class may
>   have other constructors as well. The no-arg constructor must be public
>   or protected.

You can look [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) for the spec.

Comment: thanks!  I tried that, but I am still getting the error :(

Answer (score 0):

in dataBase exists UUID type, try to use UUID instead of varchar(36).